# express.js - single routing handler for multiple routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm currently building an app and I have a routes file that looks like this.

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('statics/home'));
router.get('/jobs', (req, res) => res.render('statics/jobs'));
router.get('/about-page', (req, res) => res.render('statics/about-page'));
router.get('/valves', (req, res) => res.render('statics/valves'));

router.all('*', (req, res) => res.notFound());

module.exports = router;
```

I am trying to figure out a way to refactor my routes and have a single route that accepts any string and then checks to see if a file exists matching it

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const fs = require('fs');

router.get(':template', (req, res) => {
  const tpl = req.param('template');
  if (tpl) {
    if (fs.existsSync('/path/to/templates/' + tpl + '.ext')) { // adjust the path and template extension
      res.render('statics/' + tpl);
    } else {
      res.notFound();
    }
  } else {
    res.render('statics/home');
  }
});

router.all('*', (req, res) => res.notFound());

module.exports = router;
```

Or probably better approach would be to read the templates directory once and create routes based on its contents:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const fs = require('fs');

const templates = fs.readdirSync('/path/to/templates');
templates.forEach(tpl => {
  tpl = tpl.substring(tpl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  if (tpl === 'home') {
    router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('statics/home'))
  } else {
    router.get('/' + tpl, (req, res) => res.render('statics/' + tpl))
  }
});

router.all('*', (req, res) => res.notFound());

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much! I really like the second solution you posted. I will try to implement this today

Answer (score 1):

To easily handle static file, you can use express static,  express will automatic route all file inside static folder

```
app = require('express')();
app.use('statics',express.static('statics'));
```